# Mathematica lexer: Symbols and UTF-8

Tags: core-language, regular-expressions

Did you ever wonder why here on our site, there is a highlighting difference between

```
f[argX_] := 1;
```

and

```
f[argα_] := 1;
```

Well, now you know and it's me you can blame. It wasn't an oversight. It was a decision I made on purpose. Mathematica is one of the nowadays growing number of languages that support Unicode for their identifiers (and some operations as well).

From the viewpoint of someone that implements a highlighter like the one, we use here on Mathematica.SE, this is a real pain because it makes matching simple identifiers so much harder.

Personally, I dislike this features because it opens the way to absolutely unreadable code. I'm thinking about this

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Import["http://halirutan.github.io/Mathematica-SE-Tools/decode.m"]["https://i.stack.imgur.com/KExaQ.png"]
```

(yeah, you have to copy and evaluate it..) or remember the famous [semicolon prank](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26965332/1078614).

Nevertheless, people love writing `ξ` instead of `xi` and this is something I can understand. However, you cannot simply support *some* of the characters because the next moment someone will come around the corner and present a perfectly valid reason why he needs this one symbol you haven't included yet.

That being said, let's assume we want to support all Unicode characters that are valid as part of a symbol in Mathematica. We first have to find out, which are the ones that are valid. One way is to test with `LetterQ` in the hope it does the right thing.

As I have not much experience with Unicode or UTF-8, I lookup `FromCharacterCode` and it tells me that valid numbers are `1` to `2^16-1`. Let's make a quick check:

```
LetterQ[FromCharacterCode[#]] & /@ Range[2^16 - 1] // Tally
(* {{False, 16693}, {True, 48842}} *)
```

Is it really appropriate include almost 50k chars? What I have seen in the Julia Language parser is that they used character ranges to denote the characters they support. Therefore, here a pretty straightforward `rangify` function that creates character ranges for valid symbol letters:

```
rangify[n_Integer] := 
  With[{result = 
     rangifyC[Boole[LetterQ[FromCharacterCode[#]] & /@ Range[n]]]},
   If[Length[result] > 0,
    Partition[result, 2],
    {}
    ]
   ];
rangifyC = Compile[{{l, _Integer, 1}},
  Module[{pos = 1, current = 0, bag = Internal`Bag[Most[{0}]]},
   While[pos <= Length[l],
    current = l[[pos]];
    If[current == 1,
     Internal`StuffBag[bag, pos];
     ];
    While[l[[pos]] == current,
     pos++;
     If[pos > Length[l], Break[]];
     ];
    If[current == 1,
     Internal`StuffBag[bag, pos - 1]
     ]
    ];
   Internal`BagPart[bag, All]
   ]
  ]
```

Now, we can calculate valid character ranges

```
rangify[150]
FromCharacterCode[Range @@ #] & /@ %
(* {{65, 90}, {97, 122}} *)
(* {"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"} *)
```

To use this in all the different highlighters we have (google-prettify, pygmentize, Rogue for Jekyll pages, Atom highlighting, *maybe* IntelliJ-Plugin), we need a valid regex for those ranges that looks in JavaScript for instance like this `[\u0041-\u005a]` (numbers 65 and 90 to 4 digit hex).

```
toUtfRange[{n_, n_}] := "\\u" <> IntegerString[n, 16, 4];
toUtfRange[range_] := StringRiffle["\\u" <> IntegerString[#, 16, 4] &
  /@ range, "-"];
toRegex[n_Integer] := "[" <> StringRiffle[toUtfRange /@ rangify[n], ","] <> "]"
```

And finally we can do

```
toRegex[2^16 - 1]
```

to get (hold your breath)

```
[\u0041-\u005a,\u0061-\u007a,\u00aa,\u00b5,\u00ba,\u00c0-\u00d6,\u00d8-\u00f6,\u00f8-\u02c1,\u02c6-\u02d1,\u02e0-\u02e4,\u02ec,\u02ee,\u0370-\u0374,\u0376-\u0377,\u037a-\u037d,\u037f,\u0386,\u0388-\u038a,\u038c,\u038e-\u03a1,\u03a3-\u03f5,\u03f7-\u0481,\u048a-\u052f,\u0531-\u0556,\u0559,\u0561-\u0587,\u05d0-\u05ea,\u05f0-\u05f2,\u0620-\u064a,\u066e-\u066f,\u0671-\u06d3,\u06d5,\u06e5-\u06e6,\u06ee-\u06ef,\u06fa-\u06fc,\u06ff,\u0710,\u0712-\u072f,\u074d-\u07a5,\u07b1,\u07ca-\u07ea,\u07f4-\u07f5,\u07fa,\u0800-\u0815,\u081a,\u0824,\u0828,\u0840-\u0858,\u08a0-\u08b2,\u0904-\u0939,\u093d,\u0950,\u0958-\u0961,\u0971-\u0980,\u0985-\u098c,\u098f-\u0990,\u0993-\u09a8,\u09aa-\u09b0,\u09b2,\u09b6-\u09b9,\u09bd,\u09ce,\u09dc-\u09dd,\u09df-\u09e1,\u09f0-\u09f1,\u0a05-\u0a0a,\u0a0f-\u0a10,\u0a13-\u0a28,\u0a2a-\u0a30,\u0a32-\u0a33,\u0a35-\u0a36,\u0a38-\u0a39,\u0a59-\u0a5c,\u0a5e,\u0a72-\u0a74,\u0a85-\u0a8d,\u0a8f-\u0a91,\u0a93-\u0aa8,\u0aaa-\u0ab0,\u0ab2-\u0ab3,\u0ab5-\u0ab9,\u0abd,\u0ad0,\u0ae0-\u0ae1,\u0b05-\u0b0c,\u0b0f-\u0b10,\u0b13-\u0b28,\u0b2a-\u0b30,\u0b32-\u0b33,\u0b35-\u0b39,\u0b3d,\u0b5c-\u0b5d,\u0b5f-\u0b61,\u0b71,\u0b83,\u0b85-\u0b8a,\u0b8e-\u0b90,\u0b92-\u0b95,\u0b99-\u0b9a,\u0b9c,\u0b9e-\u0b9f,\u0ba3-\u0ba4,\u0ba8-\u0baa,\u0bae-\u0bb9,\u0bd0,\u0c05-\u0c0c,\u0c0e-\u0c10,\u0c12-\u0c28,\u0c2a-\u0c39,\u0c3d,\u0c58-\u0c59,\u0c60-\u0c61,\u0c85-\u0c8c,\u0c8e-\u0c90,\u0c92-\u0ca8,\u0caa-\u0cb3,\u0cb5-\u0cb9,\u0cbd,\u0cde,\u0ce0-\u0ce1,\u0cf1-\u0cf2,\u0d05-\u0d0c,\u0d0e-\u0d10,\u0d12-\u0d3a,\u0d3d,\u0d4e,\u0d60-\u0d61,\u0d7a-\u0d7f,\u0d85-\u0d96,\u0d9a-\u0db1,\u0db3-\u0dbb,\u0dbd,\u0dc0-\u0dc6,\u0e01-\u0e30,\u0e32-\u0e33,\u0e40-\u0e46,\u0e81-\u0e82,\u0e84,\u0e87-\u0e88,\u0e8a,\u0e8d,\u0e94-\u0e97,\u0e99-\u0e9f,\u0ea1-\u0ea3,\u0ea5,\u0ea7,\u0eaa-\u0eab,\u0ead-\u0eb0,\u0eb2-\u0eb3,\u0ebd,\u0ec0-\u0ec4,\u0ec6,\u0edc-\u0edf,\u0f00,\u0f40-\u0f47,\u0f49-\u0f6c,\u0f88-\u0f8c,\u1000-\u102a,\u103f,\u1050-\u1055,\u105a-\u105d,\u1061,\u1065-\u1066,\u106e-\u1070,\u1075-\u1081,\u108e,\u10a0-\u10c5,\u10c7,\u10cd,\u10d0-\u10fa,\u10fc-\u1248,\u124a-\u124d,\u1250-\u1256,\u1258,\u125a-\u125d,\u1260-\u1288,\u128a-\u128d,\u1290-\u12b0,\u12b2-\u12b5,\u12b8-\u12be,\u12c0,\u12c2-\u12c5,\u12c8-\u12d6,\u12d8-\u1310,\u1312-\u1315,\u1318-\u135a,\u1380-\u138f,\u13a0-\u13f4,\u1401-\u166c,\u166f-\u167f,\u1681-\u169a,\u16a0-\u16ea,\u16f1-\u16f8,\u1700-\u170c,\u170e-\u1711,\u1720-\u1731,\u1740-\u1751,\u1760-\u176c,\u176e-\u1770,\u1780-\u17b3,\u17d7,\u17dc,\u1820-\u1877,\u1880-\u18a8,\u18aa,\u18b0-\u18f5,\u1900-\u191e,\u1950-\u196d,\u1970-\u1974,\u1980-\u19ab,\u19c1-\u19c7,\u1a00-\u1a16,\u1a20-\u1a54,\u1aa7,\u1b05-\u1b33,\u1b45-\u1b4b,\u1b83-\u1ba0,\u1bae-\u1baf,\u1bba-\u1be5,\u1c00-\u1c23,\u1c4d-\u1c4f,\u1c5a-\u1c7d,\u1ce9-\u1cec,\u1cee-\u1cf1,\u1cf5-\u1cf6,\u1d00-\u1dbf,\u1e00-\u1f15,\u1f18-\u1f1d,\u1f20-\u1f45,\u1f48-\u1f4d,\u1f50-\u1f57,\u1f59,\u1f5b,\u1f5d,\u1f5f-\u1f7d,\u1f80-\u1fb4,\u1fb6-\u1fbc,\u1fbe,\u1fc2-\u1fc4,\u1fc6-\u1fcc,\u1fd0-\u1fd3,\u1fd6-\u1fdb,\u1fe0-\u1fec,\u1ff2-\u1ff4,\u1ff6-\u1ffc,\u2071,\u207f,\u2090-\u209c,\u2102,\u2107,\u210a-\u210e,\u2110-\u2113,\u2115,\u2119-\u211d,\u2124,\u2126,\u2128,\u212a,\u212c-\u212d,\u212f-\u2139,\u213c-\u213f,\u2145-\u2149,\u214e,\u2183-\u2184,\u2c00-\u2c2e,\u2c30-\u2c5e,\u2c60-\u2ce4,\u2ceb-\u2cee,\u2cf2-\u2cf3,\u2d00-\u2d25,\u2d27,\u2d2d,\u2d30-\u2d67,\u2d6f,\u2d80-\u2d96,\u2da0-\u2da6,\u2da8-\u2dae,\u2db0-\u2db6,\u2db8-\u2dbe,\u2dc0-\u2dc6,\u2dc8-\u2dce,\u2dd0-\u2dd6,\u2dd8-\u2dde,\u2e2f,\u3005-\u3006,\u3031-\u3035,\u303b-\u303c,\u3041-\u3096,\u309d-\u309f,\u30a1-\u30fa,\u30fc-\u30ff,\u3105-\u312d,\u3131-\u318e,\u31a0-\u31ba,\u31f0-\u31ff,\u3400-\u4db5,\u4e00-\u9fcc,\ua000-\ua48c,\ua4d0-\ua4fd,\ua500-\ua60c,\ua610-\ua61f,\ua62a-\ua62b,\ua640-\ua66e,\ua67f-\ua69d,\ua6a0-\ua6e5,\ua717-\ua71f,\ua722-\ua788,\ua78b-\ua78e,\ua790-\ua7ad,\ua7b0-\ua7b1,\ua7f7-\ua801,\ua803-\ua805,\ua807-\ua80a,\ua80c-\ua822,\ua840-\ua873,\ua882-\ua8b3,\ua8f2-\ua8f7,\ua8fb,\ua90a-\ua925,\ua930-\ua946,\ua960-\ua97c,\ua984-\ua9b2,\ua9cf,\ua9e0-\ua9e4,\ua9e6-\ua9ef,\ua9fa-\ua9fe,\uaa00-\uaa28,\uaa40-\uaa42,\uaa44-\uaa4b,\uaa60-\uaa76,\uaa7a,\uaa7e-\uaaaf,\uaab1,\uaab5-\uaab6,\uaab9-\uaabd,\uaac0,\uaac2,\uaadb-\uaadd,\uaae0-\uaaea,\uaaf2-\uaaf4,\uab01-\uab06,\uab09-\uab0e,\uab11-\uab16,\uab20-\uab26,\uab28-\uab2e,\uab30-\uab5a,\uab5c-\uab5f,\uab64-\uab65,\uabc0-\uabe2,\uac00-\ud7a3,\ud7b0-\ud7c6,\ud7cb-\ud7fb,\uf6b2-\uf6b5,\uf6b7,\uf6b9-\uf6bc,\uf6be-\uf6bf,\uf6c1-\uf700,\uf730-\uf731,\uf770,\uf772-\uf773,\uf776,\uf779-\uf77a,\uf77d-\uf780,\uf782-\uf78b,\uf78d-\uf790,\uf793-\uf79a,\uf79c-\uf7a2,\uf7a4-\uf7bd,\uf800-\uf844,\uf846-\uf84c,\uf854-\uf86c,\uf874-\uf875,\uf878-\uf879,\uf87d-\uf886,\uf88a,\uf900-\ufa6d,\ufa70-\ufad9,\ufb00-\ufb06,\ufb13-\ufb17,\ufb1d,\ufb1f-\ufb28,\ufb2a-\ufb36,\ufb38-\ufb3c,\ufb3e,\ufb40-\ufb41,\ufb43-\ufb44,\ufb46-\ufbb1,\ufbd3-\ufd3d,\ufd50-\ufd8f,\ufd92-\ufdc7,\ufdf0-\ufdfb,\ufe70-\ufe74,\ufe76-\ufefc,\uff21-\uff3a,\uff41-\uff5a,\uff66-\uffbe,\uffc2-\uffc7,\uffca-\uffcf,\uffd2-\uffd7,\uffda-\uffdc]
```

If you like, you can copy this beast and test it [on Online regex tester](https://regex101.com/) (don't forget to set JavaScript). The whole reason for this exercise is, that I would like to give all the implementers of highlighters a unified regex template that can be used to match all correct Mathematica symbols. I'm probably going to repeat this for numbers, which are complex to test too (look for instance [here](https://github.com/rsmenon/pygments-mathematica/issues/4#issuecomment-358695488)).

If you made it so far, thank you. My questions are

1. Does someone know if things can go badly wrong?
2. Does it even make sense to support everything?
3. What have people from e.g. Asia have to say about this? How often are you using characters that are not ASCII in your code?
4. Any tips about problems of Unicode/UTF-8 that might appear?

Please feel free to leave your comments and suggestions as answers.

Comment: I can't say anything about 1) or 3) but I would like to register my strong support for 2, in particular as it relates to people whose default language may not be primarily ASCII. They may still code in ASCII, but they'll likely often work with non-ASCII.

Comment: @b3m2a1 Yes, I forgot to mention that. I made some Asian friends over the years and was always stunned that they indeed use all the letters I can't even distinguish. I'm including this as a point. Thanks.

Comment: @halirutan first of all, no, thank you :) Now, will it not fit meta.mma.se better? With parts delegated to SO and linked? Maybe ux.se.com too?

Comment: @Kuba This question was originally planned as "How to create a list of all possible UTF characters inside Symbols" and then I thought that probably no one will answer when I do not deliver some initial work. Then I couldn't really stop. I would like to keep it here because I'm planning on followup questions about numbers and slots where I really need our user to try to break my code.

Comment: The domain you use for `FromCharacterCode` is not sufficient:  `FromDigits["1EE0E", 16] > 2^16 - 1` → `True` and `LetterQ@FromCharacterCode@FromDigits["1EE0E", 16]` → `True`.  That letter is defined in Unicode as "ARABIC MATHEMATICAL SEEN".  You will probably need to use a Unicode database.