# Mathematica lexer: Numbers

Tags: core-language, regular-expressions

This is a follow-up question to [Mathematica lexer: Symbols and UTF-8](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/164032/187) and this it is about numbers. In Mathematica, we have a large number of ways to input numbers. They can contain a notation for the base, precision, accuracy, a scientific form `*^12`, or a combination of them.

I crafted a simple `StringExpression` that should catch most cases

```
number = {DigitCharacter .., "." ~~ DigitCharacter .., 
   DigitCharacter .. ~~ "." ~~ DigitCharacter ...};
baseNumber = {HexadecimalCharacter .., "." ~~ HexadecimalCharacter ..,
    HexadecimalCharacter .. ~~ "." ~~ HexadecimalCharacter ..};
base = DigitCharacter .. ~~ "^^";
precicion = "`" ~~ RepeatedNull[RepeatedNull["`", 1] ~~ number, 1];
scientific = "*^" ~~ RepeatedNull["+" | "-", 1] ~~ DigitCharacter ..;
final = {number, base ~~ baseNumber} ~~ RepeatedNull[precicion, 1] ~~ 
   RepeatedNull[scientific, 1];

testMe[str_String] := StringMatchQ[str, final]
```

We can test this with most common forms

```
testMe /@ {"123", ".123", "123.123", "16^^aa", "16^^.aa", 
  "16^^.aa``30*^+10", "16^^0.*^3"}
(* {True, True, True, True, True, True, True} *)
```

**Question 1:** Do you find valid Mathematica numbers that return `False`? There are some restrictions:

- A leading minus sign is not allowed as this will be caught as operator later and is of no concern now.
- I implemented only up to base 16, so funny examples like

  ```
  32^^ListLinePlot
  (* 777888725646235421 *)
  ```

  are unfortunately not allowed.

**Question 2:** Do you find **invalid** number forms that return `True`? Restriction:

- While `2^^abc` is an invalid number, there is no way for the lexer to know this because when matching the `abc`, it has no knowledge about the context that you used only base `2`.