# DirectedEdge character doesn't appear when Save As HTML

Tags: export, html

The `\[DirectedEdge]` character doesn't appear when I save a notebook as HTML.

Here's the notebook, which saves itself to HTML:

[image]

Here's the HTML:

[image]

In the HTML, the `\[DirectedEdge]` is encoded as `&#62421;`, which [unicodelookup.com](https://unicodelookup.com) doesn't recognize , but which Mathematica does:

```
FromCharacterCode[62421] // CharacterName
(* DirectedEdge *)
```

I have also tried adding the option `"CSS" -> "mma.css"` to the `Export` command.

Comment: You need to link in the fonts somehow, which means linking in WRIs style sheet where they’re defined. I just always programmatically post-process, personally.

Comment: @b3m2a1, thanks. Can you explain? Do I need to link a MMA style sheet into my MMA notebook, or do you mean copying some CSS from a WRI CSS stylesheet into the CSS file generated after I "save as HTML"? Could you briefly describe how you post-process it?

Comment: The latter. I just use string replace to insert into the generated file. I think I posted about this on meta somewhere...

Comment: Thanks. In your SE post [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/167333/encoding-strings-to-workaround-clouddeployment-bugs/167334#167334) you link to [your MMA tutorial](https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1/tutorial/using-mathematica/basics/types.html) that uses the `\[Wolf]` character by linking to a [WRI CSS file `special-styles.css`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language-assets/css/special-styles.css) and using the [prettify](https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1/tutorial/theme/prettify/src/prettify.js) JavaScript.